# How to calibrate probabilities in R?

Tags: r, probability, caret, calibration

I am trying to calibrate probabilities that I get with the predict function in the R package.
I have in my case two classes and mutiple predictors. I used the iris dataset as an example for you to try and help me out.

```
my_data  <- iris %>% #reducing the data to have two classes only
  dplyr::filter((Species =="virginica" | Species == "versicolor") ) %>% dplyr::select(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width,Species)

my_data <- droplevels(my_data)

index <- createDataPartition(y=my_data$Species,p=0.6,list=FALSE) 
#creating train and test set for machine learning
Train <- my_data[index,]
Test <-  my_data[-index,]

#machine learning based on Train data partition with glmnet method
classCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=5,classProbs =  TRUE,savePredictions = "final")
set.seed(355)
glmnet_ML <- train(Species~., Train, method= "glmnet",  trControl=classCtrl)
glmnet_ML

#probabilities to assign each row of data to one class or the other on Test
predTestprob <- predict(glmnet_ML,Test,type="prob")
pred 


#trying out calibration following "Applied predictive modeling" book from Max Kuhn p266-273
predTrainprob <- predict(glmnet_ML,Train,type="prob")
predTest <- predict(glmnet_ML,Test)
predTestprob <- predict(glmnet_ML,Test,type="prob")

Test$PredProb <- predTestprob[,"versicolor"]
Test$Pred <- predTest
Train$PredProb <- predTrainprob[,"versicolor"]

#logistic regression to calibrate
sigmoidalCal <- glm(relevel(Species, ref= "virginica") ~ PredProb,data = Train,family = binomial)
coef(summary(sigmoidalCal))

#predicting calibrated scores
sigmoidProbs <- predict(sigmoidalCal,newdata = Test[,"PredProb", drop = FALSE],type = "response")
Test$CalProb <- sigmoidProbs

#plotting to see if it works
calCurve2 <- calibration(Species ~ PredProb +  CalProb, data = Test)
xyplot(calCurve2,auto.key = list(columns = 2))
```

According to me, the result given by the plot is not good which indicates a mistake in the calibration, the Calprob curve should follow the diagonal but it doe not.

Has anyone done anything similar ?

Comment: what do you mean by calibrated? please give an example of your expected result

Comment: Probabilities given by the predict function have to be calibrated for future use. [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/probability-calibration-for-imbalanced-classification/). Usually a platt scaling or isotonic regression is used to do this calibration

Comment: You need to show us your expected result.

Comment: The expected result is another column of probabilities that correspond either to B or W calibrated probabilities. A plot with non calibrated probability curve and calibrated probability curve is used to show the improvment as in [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-enforce-the-outcome-of-your-ml-classifiers-b5f6163d68c2)

Comment: You can't just link an article and expect people to guess what your expected result looks like. On stackoverflow you have to help us help you by providing a good reproducible example, and telling us exactly what you expect as a result, using example data.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully you understand my question with this example.